# SSRS - How to get subtotals for a set of 12 records in a column

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, matrix, reporting

I am novice with SSRS.

I have a report which should display 60 months (5 years displayed like Jan 1999, feb 1999 & so on till the end of 60 months) and its corresponding sales amount. I want to get averages for the first 12 months (i.e for the 1st year) and so on. Is it possible? My dataset just gives me all the 60 months row-by-row.I am using matrix for my report.

Thanks,
User007.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add some nested row grouping to the matrix.  The higher-level group would be by year, which would allow you to have a row in the matrix that totals/averages all of the data for the year.  The inner group would be by month, giving you the individual month rows as your dataset returns them.

[Here is some information about defining and using groups](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255263%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)